# javasript in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

There's a solution on js -

codepen.io/skovtun/pen/VwLvXPB

Can't make an analog for Angular8+.

I need the center block to have a fixed width (1200px), and it is evaluated and compressed by the left, right and both sidebars immediately when they are opened. They should not overlap with the content.

Comment: Describe more clearly, better to show some code

Comment: Also, drawings to show what you mean when describing layouts are helpful

Comment: @SarowerJahan this link https://codepen.io/skovtun/pen/VwLvXPB

Comment: @KurtHamilton his link https://codepen.io/skovtun/pen/VwLvXPB

Comment: Can you explain why it needs to be a javascript solution when that layout can be achieved with pure CSS

Answer (score 0):

I seen content overlapping when closing sidebars. May be you want to stop overlapping during open and close sidebar. It can be fixed by css. You can use transition in `.wrapper` class. see bellow code:

```
.wrapper{
  height: 100%;
  transition:all .25s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with pure CSS.

You haven't specified what the requirements are, but you can use flexbox like the below example to achieve a max-width main container flanked by 2 compressing sidebars.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
}

main {
  width: 1200px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.sidebar-left {
  border-right: 1px solid #06A52B;
}

.sidebar-right {
  border-left: 1px solid #06A52B;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">  
  <aside class="sidebar sidebar-left">    
    <h2>Left sidebar</h2>
    <p>Add content here</p>
  </aside>
  <main>
    <h1>Max width of this block is 1200px</h1>
  </main>
  <aside class="sidebar sidebar-right">   
    <h2>Right sidebar</h2>
    <p>Add content here</p>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Dynamic every css class Using [ngClass] Depending on your logic ..it will render when the value will change..